# Weird error in C++ runtime

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I have written a code which has 2-D vectors as components. Whenever I give my input, after 1/2 seconds it shows this error

```
"Terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘std::bad_alloc’ 
What(): std::bad_alloc

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. 
Please contact the application’s support team for more information."
```

And after that my PC slows down and the code returns an integer and until I close the .exe file it never regains its speed.

What is the reason behind this? How to avoid such errors?\
My code is http://paste.ubuntu.com/6593192/

Comment: Without you providing some more data, such as debugging results or a piece of source code, we have no slightest idea.

Comment: first post som code: are you allocating pointer in the right way? how you destroing it? do you create vectors in a loop?

Comment: My code http://paste.ubuntu.com/6593192/

Comment: Have you considered that your std::vector< std::vector<int> >  consume a lot of memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the duplicate of `int i` cause the problem?

```
int main()
{
  **int i;** //1st
  vector<int > a(6); vector<vector<int> > c;  //two vectors
  for(**int i**=0;i<6;++i)//2nd
    cin>>a[i]; //use the 2nd

  c=mco(a,i);//use the 1st, and it is uninitialized yet!
```

The weird thing is that it is not an error. the two 'i's are actually declared in the same scope. even if the 2nd is only in the 1st for, there is no scope.

In VS10 I've got an `uninitialized local variable` warning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running out of memory due to an overwhelming amount of memory allocations with your vectors. Maybe the vectors you are passing are to big compared to your memory, or the code doing the memory allocation is flawed and is over allocating.

This seems reasonable if you are saying that your system is slowing down after this happens, as when you run out of memory swapping out takes place vigorously and OS is doing bad things with various processes.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably experiencing [memory leakage](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Properly delete unneeded dynamically allocated memory using `delete p` when `p` points to single element variables and `delete[] p` when `p` points to arrays. If you don't do that and keep dynamically allocating more memory, eventually your OS will start to swap, slowing down your system, and later on your program will end up running out of memory and throwing the `bad_alloc` exception when it is unable to allocate more memory.